# search the most latest's file name

Tags: files, find, date, string

I am writing a bash script to look for a file which's **file name** is most recently and file name like:

```
...
Wed_Dec_30_16:47:41_PHT_2015.zip
Wed_Dec_30_16:00:41_PHT_2015.zip
Wed_Dec_30_16:00:41_PHT_2015.zip
Thu_Dec_31_16:49:14_PHT_2015.zip
...
```

I'm search all .zip file use `find` command and i thought maybe i need a array like:

```
readarray -t lines <<< "$(find . -type f -name '*.zip' -exec basename {} \;|tr -d '[.zip]'|tr '_' ' ')"
len=${#lines[@]}
for ((i=0;i<len;i++)); do
    echo ${lines[$i]}
done
```

And, i got all of file name (with date time) like this in terminal. it looks completly:

```
Wed Dec 30 16:47:41 PHT 2015
Wed Dec 30 16:00:35 PHT 2015
Thu Dec 31 12:14:13 PHT 2015
Thu Dec 31 12:19:34 PHT 2015
Wed Dec 30 16:49:14 PHT 2015
Thu Dec 31 13:01:11 PHT 2015
Mon Dec 28 12:35:44 PHT 2015
...
```

But, i'm not sure how can i compare those many `string` as i use `date`.

And absolutely I'm not sure it's a really and complate way to revert the file whichs string like `Wed Dec 30 16:49:14 PHT 2015` to `Wed_Dec_30_16:49:14_PHT_2015.zip`

Thanks for help.

**Edit:**

I fix my script, and i comvert 'string' to 'date' which is seconds level:

```
declare -a my_array
len=${#lines[@]}
for ((i=0;i<$len;i++));do
    my_array[$i]=`date -d "${lines[$i]}" +%s`
done
```

and choose the max one:

```
max=${my_array[0]}
for((i=0;i<$len;i++));do
    if [ ${my_array[$i]} -gt $max ];then max=${my_array[$i]};fi
done
echo $max
```

terminal:

```
1451465261
1451462435
1451535253
1451535574
1451465354
1451538071
1451277344
1451538071 <== max one
```

So, should i revert it like: `Wed_Dec_30_16:00:41_PHT_2015.zip`?

Does anyone have a simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With gnu [`sort`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) having `input.txt` as input ([explain](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sort%20-t%20_%20-k6n%2C6.4%20-k2M%20-k3n%20-k4.1n%2C4.2%20-k4.4n%2C4.5%20-k4.7n%2C4.8)):

```
cat input.txt | sort -t _ -k6n,6.4 -k2M -k3n -k4.1n,4.2 -k4.4n,4.5 -k4.7n,4.8
```

Add `--debug` flag to see fields used for sorting. Useful when you have to tweak substrings:

```
Wed_Dec_30_16:00:41_PHT_2015.zip
                        ____
    ___
        __
           __
              __
                 __
```

Comment: It's exactly what i need. 'sort' is a simple way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have your data in an array , but I tested with a file. Shouldn't matter - logic is the same.
Just convert to seconds since epoch, test which epoch number is biggest, and remember that number - thats your most recent date.  Then obviously you need to reconcile that string against your file structures to get the specific file you were looking for.

file: dates.txt

```
Wed Dec 30 16:47:41 PHT 2015
Wed Dec 30 16:00:35 PHT 2015
Thu Dec 31 12:14:13 PHT 2015
Thu Dec 31 12:19:34 PHT 2015
Wed Dec 30 16:49:14 PHT 2015
Thu Dec 31 13:01:11 PHT 2015
Mon Dec 28 12:35:44 PHT 2015
```

file: find_latest.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

newest=0

while read line
do
    i=$(awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$6}' <<<$line)
    epoch=$(date --date="$i" +'%s')
    if [ "$epoch" -gt "$newest" ]
    then
        newest=$(date --date="$i" +"%s")
    fi

done < dates.txt

echo "newest is: "$(date --date="@${newest}")
```

result:

```
newest is: Thu Dec 31 13:01:11 NZDT 2015
```

Comment: Thanks, it works completely. it help me solve the problem and make my code more simplify, no redundance. thank you.